# Ordering shapes across groups

Tags: d3.js, svg

I know, that in SVG shapes are displayed in the order the elements are listed in the document, so by re-ordering them you can bring needed shapes to front. However, suppose, I have a document like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="500" version="1.1">
   <g transform="translate(10, 10)">
       <rect width="200" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="6" x="10" y="10" fill="green"/>
       <rect width="200" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="6" x="50" y="50" fill="red"/>
   </g>
   <g transform="translate(80, 80)">
       <rect width="200" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="6" x="10" y="10" fill="green"/>
       <rect width="200" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="6" x="50" y="50" fill="red"/>
   </g>
</svg>
```

(See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6aLocdoe/1/)). Within each group the elements are arranged so, that the red rectangles are shown on top of the corresponding green ones. However, because the groups are ordered as well, the second group is on top of the first one. I want all red rectangles to be shown on top of all green rectangles, *and* remain grouped like above. Is that possible in SVG / D3.js?

Comment: Move the red rectangles to the second group and move the green rectangles to the first group.

Comment: @RobertLongson "...*and* remain grouped like above". I have reasons for that (the groups are managed separately, have separate data appended etc).

Comment: Put the existing groups within a `<defs>` element and use `<use>` tags to pick out the individual elements you want to render in the order you want to render them.

Comment: @RobertLongson will that lose the grouped positioning (`transform="..."`)?

Comment: You'd have to add that back in via a transform on the individual `<use>` elements

Comment: What about remove the old one, and draw a new rect if you want to some thing like `z-index` which not works in svg?

Comment: you say any of the red rectangles, do you mean all ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy yes. Will update the question to clarify.

Comment: can you not give them classes, and instead of translating the group, translate the class ? So that way they can be in different groups ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy besides using groups for attributes, I append data to the corresponding DOM. Apparently, any solution would require significant re-structuring of the document, I hoped there was some quick workaround.

Comment: yep, any solution, at least i think, would, like you say, require re-structuring. I don't have any other options :(